# Docker / WSL / Symfony / MySQL - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL 2 and trying to connect to my MySQL database though my docker app container (Symfony 4.4). The other posts about this subject did not helped me to find a solution, that is why I asking you now. Don't hesitate to ask me to add other files which can help us to get more informations about this problem.

All of the containers are ostensibly running fine ([details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYrJD.png)).

Then I go inside my app container with `docker exec -it app-backend-fairfair bash` and run `composer install` with success. It works fine ([details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb2WH.png)).

Finally I run `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` but it won't work even if I have an full database access though Adminer on the localhost:8081, I still get the `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` error. The full error message [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqZp6.png).

---

**Files used**

Here is my docker .env file :

```
SERVER_PORT=8080
ADMINER_PORT=8081

# name and group of your user
HOST_USER=shamzic

# Path to store data in your machine
MYSQL_VOLUME=/var/docker-volume/fairfair/database

# Password for root user
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

Inside the .env symfony container file :

```
...

DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@db:3306/main
...
```

The docker-compose.yaml file :

```yaml
version: '3.2'

services:
    app-backend-fairfair:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: app.dockerfile
            args:
                USER: ${HOST_USER}
        volumes:
            - '../../:/usr/src/backend-fairfair'
        networks:
            - app-backend-fairfair
            - db
        restart: on-failure
        container_name: app-backend-fairfair
    server-backend-fairfair:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: server.dockerfile
        networks:
            - app-backend-fairfair
        ports:
            - ${SERVER_PORT}:80
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
            - app-backend-fairfair
        container_name: server-backend-fairfair
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: database.dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ${MYSQL_VOLUME}:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        networks:
            - db
        restart: on-failure
        container_name: db
    adminer:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: adminer.dockerfile
        ports:
            - ${ADMINER_PORT}:8080
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
            - db
        depends_on:
            - db
        container_name: adminer
networks:
    app-backend-fairfair:
        name: app-backend-fairfair
    db:
        name: db
```

I'm conviced that this can be fixed by few changes... Maybe inside the docker-compose.yaml file ?

Thank you by advance for your help !

Comment: Can you connect to your db using root credentials outside of the db container?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks fine and it should be enough to work as expected.

The error message also indicates that the networking setup is working and the db host can be resolved but it is not accepting connections. Most probably the db is just not ready to accept connections *yet*. Just waiting for it to finish initializing might be enough.

So verify that the `mysql` service has finished initializing by checking the log output of that service:

```sh
docker-compose logs db
```

Then verify that it is accepting connections on the local interface/unix socket:

```sh
docker-compose exec db mysql -u root -proot
```

Next you can verify that mysql is accepting connection on its (from the container's point of view) external interface:

```sh
docker-compose run --rm db mysql -h db -u root -proot
```